# Modify the text using a "struct" in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I have a following verse:

```
A swarm of bees in May
Is worth a load hey;
A swarm of bees in June
Is worth a silver spoon;
A swarm of bees in July
Is hot a worth a fly.
```

And I have to modify this text so that all lines ended in the same position.
Insufficient number of positions in the string complement using the spaces. These spaces must be divided evenly
I know that my code is very bulky, but I must use a "struct in my code"

How can I find the longest string and add spaces in others to perform the task?

Thanks!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <string.h> 
using namespace std;

struct VERSE {
    char row_one[25];
    char row_two[25];
    char row_three[25];
    char row_four[25];
    char row_five[25];
    char row_six[25];
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    struct VERSE v;
    strcpy_s(v.row_one, "A swarm of bees in May");
    strcpy_s(v.row_two, "Is worth a load hey;");
    strcpy_s(v.row_three, "A swarm of bees in June");
    strcpy_s(v.row_four, "Is worth a silver spoon;");
    strcpy_s(v.row_five, "A swarm of bees in July");
    strcpy_s(v.row_six, "Is hot a worth a fly.");
    cout << v.row_one << endl << v.row_two << endl << v.row_three << endl
        << v.row_four << endl << v.row_five << endl << v.row_six << endl;

    cout << strlen(v.row_one) << endl;
    cout << strlen(v.row_two) << endl;
    cout << strlen(v.row_three) << endl;
    cout << strlen(v.row_four) << endl;
    cout << strlen(v.row_five) << endl;
    cout << strlen(v.row_six) << endl;

    //the length of row
    /*
    int length = 0;
    for(int i = 0; v.row_two[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        length++;
    }
    printf("Length of second row is: %d\n", length);
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't cross tag C and C++, the languages are very different. Also, you should be using `std::string` instead of C strings. You might also want to use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a fixed number of "rows". Then your code becomes very simple.

Comment: "Insufficient number of positions in the string complement using the spaces" I don't understand this.

Comment: Also drop `struct` from `struct VERSE v;`, C++ does not need it.

Comment: are you not allowed to use `std::vector<>` and `std::string`? If this is some exercise, you have no choice but to manually check each member of the `struct` for it's length, get the maximum, and then do the same again, this time adding spaces to the "rows" that are less..

Comment: @NeilKirk: He wants to complement the existing characters with new space characters injected between words, such that the final length of each sentence is the same.

Comment: You should consider the width operator of cout instead of changing your individual strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A swarm of bees in May
Is worth a load hey;
A swarm of bees in June
Is worth a silver spoon;
A swarm of bees in July
Is hot a worth a fly.
```

Is just annoying me. I want to re-write it as:

```
A swarm of bees in May
Is worth a load of hay;
A swarm of bees in June
Is worth a silver spoon;
A swarm of bees in July
Is not worth a fly.
```

Anyway, with that out of the way:

I am writing this answer assuming that this is an assignment and that you have been told to use c_strings. If this is not the case, then using `std::string` would make it easier.

Anyway, I have come up with this code:

```
#include "iostream"
#include <string.h> 
using namespace std;

const int maxrowlength = 25, maxrowcount = 6;

struct VERSE {
    char rows[maxrowcount][maxrowlength];
    int spaces[maxrowcount];
    int line_length[maxrowcount];
};

char* get_row(VERSE &v, int row)
{
    return &v.rows[row][0];
}

int main()
{
    struct VERSE v;
    strcpy(get_row(v,0), "A swarm of bees in May");
    strcpy(get_row(v,1), "Is worth a load hey;");
    strcpy(get_row(v,2), "A swarm of bees in June");
    strcpy(get_row(v,3), "Is worth a silver spoon;");
    strcpy(get_row(v,4), "A swarm of bees in July");
    strcpy(get_row(v,5), "Is hot a worth a fly.");

    //calculate lengths and count spaces
    int max_space_count = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < maxrowcount; i++)
    {
        char* line = get_row(v,i);
        /*/we could find the length with strlen() and spaces with memchr() but 
           that will involve traversing the string multiple times (at least twice)
           we can do better
        /*/
        v.line_length[i] = 0;
        v.spaces[i] = 0;

        while(*line)
        {
            v.line_length[i]++;
            if(*line == ' '){v.spaces[i]++;}
            line++;
        }
        if (v.line_length[i] > max_space_count){max_space_count = v.line_length[i];}
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < maxrowcount; i++)
    {
        int length_diff = max_space_count - v.line_length[i];
        int spaces_to_add = v.spaces[i]?length_diff / v.spaces[i]:0; //number of spaces to add every word
        int extra_spaces  = v.spaces[i]?length_diff % v.spaces[i]:0; //extra spaces to add to make line fit
        char output[maxrowlength];
        char* current_output = output;
        char* current_word = get_row(v,i);
        char* current_word_end = current_word;

        while(*current_word)
        {
            current_word_end++;
            if (*current_word_end == ' ' || *current_word_end == '\0')
            {
                //write word to output
                strncpy(current_output, current_word, current_word_end - current_word);
                //update pointer to end of new word
                current_output += current_word_end - current_word;
                //write in the number of new spaces needed
                if (*current_word_end == ' ')
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < spaces_to_add; j++)
                    {
                        *current_output = ' ';
                         current_output++;
                    }
                    //if extra spaces are needed, add those too
                    if (extra_spaces)
                    {
                        extra_spaces--;
                        *current_output = ' ';
                         current_output++;
                    }
                }
                //step current word to look at the next word
                current_word = current_word_end;
            }
        }
        //null terminate
        *current_output = '\0';
        strcpy(get_row(v,i),output);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < maxrowcount; i++)
        {std::cout << get_row(v,i) << std::endl;}

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
A  swarm  of bees in May
Is  worth  a  load  hey;
A  swarm of bees in June
Is worth a silver spoon;
A  swarm of bees in July
Is  hot  a  worth a fly.
```

See it here: <kbd>[On Ideone](http://ideone.com/li2RUi)</kbd>

It works like so:

1. Read in lines
2. Find the length of each line and count the spaces in it, find the max length
3. For the line, calculate the number of spaces needed, find out how many needed for each word, and how many left over
4. put each word in turn into output buffer
5. put in the required number of spaces
6. loop back to 4 if line not complete
7. null terminate the output
8. loop back to 3 if full input not processed
9. Lines are done.

I wrote this based off of your code, so there are a few things I would have done differently from scratch:

- `line` struct instead of your `VERSE`

  - each `line` holds it's content, number of spaces and length
  - `line`s to be stored in an array - which forms the verse

This is probably what the intent of this assignment was, but should be pretty easy to do now that your algorithm works (I'm not going to do *everything* for you) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the object `std::string` to store your lines.
Then, use the function `std::max` :

```
unsigned long int max_size = std::max(str1.length(),str2.length());
max_size = std::max(max_size, str3.length());
max_size = std::max(max_size, str4.length());
//...
```